# Evening landing (or take-off) pictured on photo

Tags: air-travel, airports, identify-this, photography

Can someone help me by identifying where is this picture taken?

[image]

I understand that it might be little bit challenging to identify a city only by its evening-lights pattern. However, I imagine that street shape pictured here is unique enough to precisely name the city.

Comment: Always do an Image Search first!

Comment: I wish this had not been solvable via Google Image Search... was looking forward to the challenge!

Comment: And just to let you know, it is a takeoff since the flaps are not deployed. They would be sticking way out if the plane was landing.

Comment: I have some [similar shots](https://goo.gl/photos/KVLpV718c2yxNhb5A) that I recently took.

Comment: @BrianRisk Because this is solvable via simple 30-seconds GI search and because this is no challenge at all, I'm especially surprised that instead of getting VTC, question gets 15+ up-votes and corresponding answer gets 35+ votes. Positively, yet still surprised. And... again... shame on me for not performing that GI search.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The image comes from [this Airliners.net page](http://www.airliners.net/photo/British-Airways/Boeing-777-236/1659619) by photographer Ken Iwelumo, where it has this caption:

> A night time aerial view of EWR and the Newark New Jersey area. Taken
>   shortly after we took off from runway 22R. From left to right: City of
>   Newark (top left corner), Weequahic Park (dark patch), City of
>   Elizabeth, EWR (dark patch with red line of lights), New Jersey
>   Turnpike, Port Newark, Port Elizabeth, Goethals Bridge to Staten
>   Island, Exxon Bayway Refinery (behind wing) plus bits of Jersey City,
>   Bayonne and Manhattan at top right corner. [Nikon D300].

You can see Newark Airport, which matches up with [this other photo](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_Qj2mlsG4gI/maxresdefault.jpg) of the terminal and runways at night.

Comment: For reference, I used Google Image Search first. That's a lot easier than recognizing New Jersey "landmarks" at night from the air. The refinery is a pretty big clue though.

Answer (score 11):

Newark, NJ.

If you try a simple Google (image) search, you will find it, and also its copyright: http://www.airliners.net/photo/British-Airways/Boeing-777-236/1659619/L

Comment: Google Image Search... shame on me! :>

Comment: Right click - search by image... 1st result.

Comment: @SeanR I think, that Aganju's smash into my face is enough, so you don't necessarily have to step on me again! :> I'm already lying in a shame!